# jquery attr not working in ie8

Tags: jquery

Can someone help me figure out why the code here is not working? I am pretty sure it has something to do with the .attr:  http://jsfiddle.net/nBcrY/1/

Comment: I'd recommend looking into Youtube API instead of using jquery for this.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work in IE because IE doesn't use the `object` tag. It uses `embed`.

It wouldn't try to change object on the fly like you are doing. Remove the object (and nested embed) completely and add it again with the new values.

BTW for youtube you should be using the iframe method anyway. http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html